# Query in Nhibernate

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, nhibernate

I am creating a winform application where I use Nhibernate. In my app I need to select all products in my database (74000 rows).

On my product object I have a list of objects, called barcodes.

I want to select all my products but the list of barcodes on earch product should only be filled with objects if the barcodetype = 20 and groupid = 4

I don't know how to write this query, I have been trying with detached criteria, but I can't get it to work. Can anybody help me writing the query, or with a link to a page where I can see how its done?

Comment: WHY do you need to select ALL 74,000 rows?

Comment: I need it for an Export method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a collection can't be "half-loaded", you need a projection.

This is how **I** usually do it:

```
var result = session.CreateQuery(@"
    select product, barcode
    from Product product
    join product.Barcodes barcode
    where barcode.Barcodetype = 20
    and barcode.Groupid = 4
    ")
    .List<object[]>()
    .ToLookup(x => (Product)x[0], x => (Barcode)x[1]);
```

(I have assumed you have scalar properties called Barcodetype and Groupid, since you didn't specify any relationships, and that all products have at least one barcode of that type)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Will that statement give me all 74000 records and all the barcodes for the products where the type is 20 and groupid is 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than instantiate all the Product objects and a subset of their Barcodes, how about using Criteria against Barcode, filtering by the type/group mentioned and joining onto the parent product.

Then use an AliasToBeanResultTransformer to populate a list of simple DTO objects.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply.
I'm very new to Nhibernate, could you provide me with an example, or maybe post a link where I can read about it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, i did it with an outer left join
      crit.CreateCriteria("barcodeses", "bc", SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).Add(Expression.Or(Expression.Eq("bc.Groupid", CType(cbBarcodeGroup.SelectedItem, Domain.Barcodegroup).ID), Expression.IsNull("bc.Groupid")))